# Dynamic Spotify Playlist of my Top Tracks on Last.fm?

Tags: playlists, spotify, last.fm

Is there anyway to create a dynamic Spotify Playlist which automatically updates with the Top 100 tracks from my Last.fm account?

I know it's possible to create a playlist of my Last.fm loved tracks using [Spotibot](http://www.spotibot.com/loved/), but they don't seem to support the creation of Top Tracks playlists.

Answer (score 4):

**Spotlistr** can generate a [Spotify playlist based on your top-listens on Last.fm](http://spotlistr.herokuapp.com/#/search/lastfm-top-for-time-period) within a customizable time period for you. In my opinion, this really should have been a default feature in Spotify or at least Last.fm.

Comment: You should really emphasize "based on your top-listens" because that's what it does, it won't put your actual top tracks in the playlist.

Comment: Actually, never mind what I said earlier. The top menu of Spotlistr contains an option to fetch top tracks for any time period. I didn't find this option earlier as it is not mentioned in the wizard on the home page of Spotlistr.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [spiff-radio.org wizard](http://www.spiff-radio.org/tracklist-wizard/) ?

Comment: This service has been discontinued.

Comment: Nope, it still works : https://www.spiff-radio.org/importer/

Comment: This tool seems great but it will only take the top 50 tracks from Last.fm, you can't configure it to take more.

Comment: @Rudey technically it's possible, fill a bug report : https://github.com/gordielachance/wp-soundsystem/issues